# error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘list1’, which is of non-class type ‘float*’

Tags: c++, arrays

my.cpp: In function ‘float minOfList(float*)’:
my.cpp:25:35: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘list1’, which is of non-class type ‘float*’
     for (int item=1; item < list1.size(); item++) {
}

minOfList is a function that's supposed to take an array of floating point values. Apparently, it can't seem to get the size of the array for some reason. I'm not sure why. Here is the full function:

```
float minOfList(float *list1) {
   float lowest = list1[0];
   float lowest2 = 0.0;
   for (int item=1; item < list1.size(); item++) {
      if (list1[item]<lowest) {
         lowest2 = lowest;
         lowest = list1[item];
    }
}
return lowest, lowest2;

}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: since float is primitive non-class type, you should pass another argument like 'int list_size'

Answer (score 0):

The `size()` method is available only on STL containers (`std::vector`, `std::list` etc). Your `list1` is simply a pointer to `float` (pointing, presumably, to an array of floats).

C-style arrays do not generally know their own length (unlike STL containers). The better solution is to use an STL container, but failing that, you need to pass in `length` as a separate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers do not have a member named `size`. You have a pointer in `minOfList`, not an array. You can't pass an array by value to a function.

Don't use C style arrays, instead use `std::vector<float>`, which *does* have a member named `size`, but also allows you to use a range-for

Also you are not returning two values, you are discarding one value in the return statement.

```
std::pair<float, float> min2OfList(const std::vector<float> & list1)
{
    // check list1.size() > 1?

    float lowest = list1[0];
    float lowest2 = 0.0;
    for (float value : list1)
    {
        if (value < lowest) {
            lowest2 = lowest;
            lowest = value;
        }
    }
    return { lowest, lowest2 };
}
```